# What is the probability that the hand will contain the A K Q J 10 of spades.

Tags: probability, permutations

A Bridge hand consists of 13 random cards taken from a deck that holds 52
cards.

1. What is the probability that the hand will contain the A K Q J 10 of
   spades.
2. What is the probability of obtaining the A K Q J 10 of at least one suit.

So far, I only know that this is the probability of getting 5 spades: P=$13!\over5!⋅8!$⋅$39!\over8!⋅31!$
\over$52!\over13!⋅39!$ and I get lost from there.

Comment: You might have an easier time writing using binomial coefficients instead of using factorials., $\binom{13}{5}\binom{39}{8}/\binom{52}{13}$ is indeed the probability of getting exactly five spades in a hand.  We are however looking for the probability of getting very specifically the A,K,Q,J,10 of spades and eight other cards, some of which are allowed to be spades as well.  How many ways are there to choose the eight other cards?  Well... we want to pick eight cards from the cards that aren't AKQJ10 of spades... so...

Comment: For the second part of the problem, use [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability for 1) should be
$$\frac{\binom{52-5}{13-5}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$
because we have to choose just $8=13-5$ cards (see JMoravitz's comment).

As regards 2), for $1\leq k\leq 5$, the probability that hand will not contain $k$ values among A K Q J 10 is
$$p_k:=\frac{\binom{52-4k}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}.$$
Then we use [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability):
$$p:=1+\sum_{k=1}^5(-1)^k\binom{5}{k}p_k$$

Comment: can you clarify better about " ..k cards among the values .." ?

Comment: @GCab I edited my answer and $p_k$ is "the probability that hand will not contain $k$ values among A K Q J 10". For example the probability that the hand does bot contain any A, Q and J is $p_3$.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the probability that a $13$-card bridge hand contains the ace, king, queen, jack, and 10 of spades?

Such a hand must contain eight of the other $52 - 5 = 47$ cards in the deck.  Hence, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{47}{8}}{\dbinom{52}{13}}$$

> What is the probability that a $13$-card bridge hand contains the ace, king, queen, jack, and 10 of at least one suit.

Since $3 \cdot 5 = 15 > 13$, the bridge hand contains an ace, king, queen, jack, and 10 of at most two suits.

Hands with an ace, king, queen, jack, and 10 of one suit:  Choose which suit will have the specified cards.  Choose the remaining eight cards in the hand from the remaining $47$ cards in the deck.

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{47}{8}$$

Notice that the other eight cards may include a second suit from which an ace, king, queen, jack, and 10 are drawn.  We have counted those hands twice, once for each way we could designate one of those suits as the suit containing those cards.  Therefore, we must subtract those hands that an ace, king, queen, king, jack, and 10 of two suits from the total.

Hands with the ace, king, queen, jack, and 10 of two suits:  Choose which two of the four suits will have the desired cards.  Choose which three of the $52 - 2 \cdot 5 = 42$ cards remaining in the deck will be in the hand.

> $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{42}{3}$$

Therefore, the number of bride hands that contain the ace, king, queen, jack, and 10 of at least one suit is

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{47}{8} - \binom{4}{2}\binom{42}{3}$$

from which you can calculate the probability.

Comment: The probability for 1) should be $\frac{\binom{47}{8}}{\binom{52}{13}}$.

Comment: @RobertZ  I said it in words, but then wrote down the wrong number.  Thank you for pointing out the error.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Shouldn't it be a plus rather than minus ? Not sure just asking...$\binom{4}{1}\binom{47}{8} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{42}{3}$

Comment: @Isham No.  Perhaps "of one suit" is misleading.   What I counted is the number of hands with an ace, king, queen, jack, and 10 of a suit.  That does not preclude the possibility that the hand contains more than one suit with an ace, king, queen, jack, and 10 of that suit.  Such hands are counted twice in the initial calculation, once for each way we could designate a particular suit as being the one with an ace, king, queen, jack, and 10 of that suit.  We must subtract hands with two such suits so that we count them only once.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for the clarification.